# Framelayout layout_width on extending

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view which extends RelativeLayout. I inflate a layout which I created using xml and contains a single element. Afterwards I add a non fixed amount of other child views to the layout in an init method called from the constructor. I need to have access to the layout_width parameter from the MainActivity xml file, as I arrange the children views in a circle with an offset which should differ according to the width given on the MainActivity xml.
I can't seem to be able to get the width given on the XML via parameter layout_width.
OnMeasure seems to get it but it is called later. 
In simpler words, I want to place the children views differently depending on the width of the view.

Comment: getLayoutParams() isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: Nope, it brings back a null.

Comment: so get it directly from AttributeSet parameter,  i still wonder what you need it for as the value can be match_parent or wrap_content, what will you do in such case?

Comment: You raise a good question. I have tried getting it from the attribute set but I was not successful. I have managed getting other attributes but not that one.

Comment: again: what if you get -1 (match_parent) ?

Comment: if it is a wrap content / match parent I want to give it a predefined constant value.

Comment: so in this case you can easily use TypedArray.getLayoutDimension